# Can I set access key as CTRL+key?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I want to set access key for my search box. By default element with access key is accessed using "ALT+KeyName". But I want know if I can set an access key value to "CTRL+keyName" using html, javascript, jquery or may be php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you cannot. This behaviour is controlled by each browser in it's own unique way. More details can be found on how each browser performs this here.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp